# Converting UTC timestamp to PST in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

Is there a straightforward way to convert UTC timestamps in SQL Server (T-SQL) to PST timestamps which also takes care of DST. I have column called X which contains datetime in UTC and I want to create one more column Y which will have times in PST, it should be less 7 or 8 hours than UTC timestamp depending on if DST was in effect or not.

Comment: what's you database? if using SQL server 2016 and above you can use 'at time zone '

Comment: @RaseenaAbdul its gives me a datetimeoffset object i think. for example if my time is 2021-01-25 00:23:18.080, X AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time' will give me 2021-01-25 00:23:18.080 -08:00 . how do i actually subtract 8 hours to get the correct time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your time is already UTC, you could do something similar to below

```
SELECT (<yourtime> at time zone 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'
```

DB FIddle : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35a8ff03cac46ab9e51d97300e993f2c

Comment: Already tried this. The return type of this function is datetimeoffset. I want the values in datetime object. This will give me values like 2021-01-25 21:00:00 -08:00 , i want the output to be  2021-01-25 13:00:00

Comment: thanks. This worked. SELECT X, CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(DATETIMEOFFSET, (X at time zone 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))
 FROM database